# C# - Processing Threads Help

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am learning Threads. I am using thread to process an  array of integers and strings.

Example :

```
class Program
{
  static void Main()
   {
     ArrayProcess pr=new ArrayProcess();
     ThreadStart callback1 = new ThreadStart(pr.PrintNumbers);
     ThreadStart callback2 = new ThreadStart(pr.PrintStrings);
     callback1 += callback2;
     Thread secondaryThread = new Thread(callback1);
     secondaryThread.Name = "worker1";
     secondaryThread.Start();
     Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
 }


class ArrayProcess
{
public void PrintNumbers()
{
    int[] a = new int[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
    foreach (int i in a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Printing Numbers");
    }

}


public void PrintStrings()
{
    string[] str = new string[] { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };
    foreach (string st in str)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(st);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Printing string");
    }
}

 }
```

*According to the code the execution of arrays are synchronous (i.e) int array is processed first and then the string array.Now how can i redesign the code to achieve asynchronous execution* 


**(i.e) 10,20,One,30,two,three,...**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually only creating one extra thread.  Try this to get two, asynchronous threads:

```
 ThreadStart callback1 = new ThreadStart(pr.PrintNumbers);
 ThreadStart callback2 = new ThreadStart(pr.PrintStrings);

 Thread t1 = new Thread(callback1);
 Thread t2 = new Thread(callback2);
 t1.Name = "worker1";
 t1.Start();
 t2.Name = "worker2";
 t2.Start();
```

Once you have mastered the basics of threads, I suggest you look into [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(VS.95).aspx) as a much easier way to manage threading.